# How to save a tuple to excel in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have fetched some data from an application and the output is in tuple.

```
deals

(   

  Instrument Date Announced  SDC Deal No
 0  154085693165     2020-07-16   3577020040
 1  154086829977     2020-07-16   3603239040
 2  154086830011     2020-07-16   3603259040
 3  154086830078     2020-07-16   3603284040
 4  154086830341     2020-07-16   3603413040,
 None)
```

How do i save this to an xlsx file using python?

Comment: This might be useful: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Stack Over Flow is not a people write code for you for free.

Comment: Take a look at tablib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tuple returns 2 values. One with the data frame and other with any error.
In this case. So the below code helps.

```
datframe,error=ek.function_name(argument1,argument2,...)
```

or,

```
deals,e=ek.get_data(common_name,company_id)
```

So now

print(deals) returns

```
Instrument Date Announced  SDC Deal No
 0  154085693165     2020-07-16   3577020040
 1  154086829977     2020-07-16   3603239040
 2  154086830011     2020-07-16   3603259040
 3  154086830078     2020-07-16   3603284040
 4  154086830341     2020-07-16   3603413040
```

and print(e) returns

```
none
```

Comment: Finally an answer trying to show the **why**, not a workaround instead. +1

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv

deals = list(deals)

with open("NameOfFile.csv",  "w") as csvfile:
    write = csv.writer(csvfile)
    
    for x in deals:
        write.writerow(map(lambda x: [x], deals))
```

This should work. This is taken (slightly modified) from [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) docs for Python.

Comment: I have tried this. but getting this error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: Then, instead of "wb" try using "w". Check my edited post.

Comment: 5 
      6     for x in deals:
----> 7         write.writerow(x)

Error: iterable expected, not NoneType

Comment: Is your deals tuple ONE HUGE TUPLE or TUPLE OF TUPLES?

Comment: It's a huge tuple.

Comment: Then try turning that tuple to a list and try running the program again. You can do that by doing list(deals)

Comment: This gives the same error. Error: iterable expected, not NoneType

Comment: I have one more idea, then I don't know how else to help :c try checking out Pandas or Numpy.

Comment: Luck or no luck?

Comment: This got saved to an excel but all the values came in one cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(deals)
df.head()
```

Can you see what you get from this? After you editted your index and columns, you can run:

```
df.to_excel('name.xls')
```

Comment: The df looks like this 
0
0
Instrument Date Announced SDC Deal No 0 ...
1
None

Comment: I am confused, can you do print(deals[:5]) and share the output?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like below code to write a list of string in a csv file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

deals = ("Instrument", "Date", "Announced",  "SDC", "Deal", "No")

x = []
for j in range(0,len(deals)):
    x.append(str(deals[j]))

with open("myfile.txt", "w") as file1:
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        file1.write(x[i])
```